# Determine radius of convergence of Taylor series of $f(z)$ at point $a$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider
$$f(z) = \frac{z+e^z}{(z-1+i)(z^2-2)(z-3i)}, a=0 $$
As we can see it's quite ugly so I won't even try and develop a Taylor series of it at point $a=0$. I have noticed there are Four singularities and the function is definitely analytical in $B(0,\sqrt{2})$ hence $\sqrt{2}$ should be the radius of convergence, because an analytical function's power series with a positive radius of convergence at point $a$ is its own Taylor series.

This seems rather sloppy justification and I'm not entirely convinced it's the way to go about it. I can be fairly sure we don't have find the actual Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{z+e^z}{(z-1+i)(z^2-2)(z-3i)}$ has four singularities at $1-i, \sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$ and $3i$.

The taylor series around $0$ will converge on any disk about $0$ in which the function is analytic and the largest of such discs has radius $\sqrt{2}$ (look at the distances from $0$ of the four singularities I mentioned).

**EDIT:** What is radius of convergence about $a \in \mathbb{C}$? It is the radius of the largest disc around $a$ in which the power series converges right? So it you take a disk any larger than $\sqrt{2}$ you will encounter the singularities and hence the Taylor series is not valid there!